# Cassandra: Update multiple rows with different values

Tags: sql, cassandra, cql, nosql

Hi I have similar table in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable( id text, 
        group text,
        date text,
        user text,
        dept text,
        orderby int,
        files list<text>,
        users list<text>, 
        family_memebrs list<frozen <member>>,
        PRIMARY KEY ((id)));'
CREATE INDEX on TestTable (user);
CREATE INDEX on TestTable (dept);
CREATE INDEX on TestTable (group);
CREATE INDEX on TestTable (date);
```

---

```
 Id    | OrderBy
:----  | :----
101    |  1
102    |  2
105    |  3
```

I want to change existing order by for following ids 105,102,103 in same order. i.e., (105, 1) (102, 2) (103, 3). I'm new to Cassandra, please help me. I think it is possible in sql byusing rownum and join.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your `CREATE TABLE` statement?  The only way this can really work they way you're thinking from the SQL world, is if they all share the same partition key.  And even then, it depends what your clustering keys are.

Comment: I added table creation

Comment: Also, the use of high-cardinality secondary indexes is an anti-pattern.  Depending on their range of values, `dept` and `group` might be ok, but `user` and `date` will too unique to perform well.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm new to Cassandra

I can tell.  The first clue, was the order of your results.  With `id` as your sole PRIMARY KEY (making it your partition key) your results would never come back sorted like that.  *This* is how they should be sorted:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT id,orderby,token(id) FROM testtable  ;

 id  | orderby | system.token(id)
-----+---------+---------------------
 102 |       2 | -963541259029995480
 105 |       3 | 2376737131193407616
 101 |       1 | 4965004472028601333

(3 rows)
```

Unbound queries always return results sorted by the hashed token value of the partition key.  I have run the `token()` function on your partition key (`id`) to show this.

> I want to change existing order by for following ids 105,102,103 in same order. i.e., (105, 1) (102, 2) (103, 3).

If all you need to do is change the values in the `orderby` column, that's easy:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO testtable(id,orderby) VALUES ('101',3);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO testtable(id,orderby) VALUES ('102',2);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO testtable(id,orderby) VALUES ('105',1);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT id,orderby,token(id) FROM testtable  ;

 id  | orderby | system.token(id)
-----+---------+---------------------
 102 |       2 | -963541259029995480
 105 |       1 | 2376737131193407616
 101 |       3 | 4965004472028601333

(3 rows)
```

As Cassandra PRIMARY KEYs are unique, simply INSERTing a new non-key column value for that key changes `orderby`.

Now if you want to actually be able to sort your results by the `orderby` column, that's another issue entirely, and cannot be solved with your current model.

If that's what you really want to do, then you'll need a new table with a different PRIMARY KEY definition.  So I'll create the same table with two changes: I'll name it `testtable_by_group`, and I'll use a composite PRIMARY KEY of `PRIMARY KEY (group,orderby,id))`.  Now I can query for a specific group "group1" and see the results sorted.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE testtable_by_group (group text,id text,orderby int,PRIMARY KEY (group,orderby,id));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO testtable_by_group(group,id,orderby) VALUES ('group1','101',3);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO testtable_by_group(group,id,orderby) VALUES ('group1','102',2);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO testtable_by_group(group,id,orderby) VALUES ('group1','105',1);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT group,id,orderby,token(group) FROM testtable_by_group WHERE group='group1';

 group  | id  | orderby | system.token(group)
--------+-----+---------+----------------------
 group1 | 105 |       1 | -2413872665919611707
 group1 | 102 |       2 | -2413872665919611707
 group1 | 101 |       3 | -2413872665919611707

(3 rows)
```

In this way, `group` is the new partition key.  `orderby` is the first clustering key, so your rows within `group` are automatically sorted by it.  `id` is on the end to ensure uniqueness, if any two rows have the same `orderby`.

Note that I left the `token()` function in the result set, but that I ran it on the new partition key (`group`).  As you can see, the key of `group1` is hashed to the same token for all 3 rows, which means that in a multi-node environment all 3 rows will be stored together.  This can create a "hotspot" in your cluster, where some nodes have more data than others.  That's why a good PRIMARY KEY definition ensures both query satisfaction *and* data distribution.

I wrote an article for DataStax on this topic a while back.  Give it a read, and it should help you out: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: Thank you very much. Requirement was changed and switched to Postgres